# More JSON and Android Problems

Tags: android, json

I'm trying to parse some JSON in my android APP. However I'm getting two errors. First one is "Value of type string cannot be converted to JSON Object" (this error I have gotten rid of by changing a few lines of code, but likely messed something up but I don't know yet cause the app is running). The second error is a null pointer error.

I know there is a lot of code on here about this already by they all use the hive tutorial to jump straight into an array. I've tried editing this code to get my JSON into a ListView but just can't quite get it. I think my problem is that I'm returning a JSONObject in the parser, which is calling my very first object (Identified), then my code immediately jumps into the array, which there isn't one because Identified isn't the array, information is. So how, in code, can I get the object of Identified, and then get the object of information (thereby jumping into the information array with the above code)? I've never done JSON parsing so it's kind of difficult for me. I'm pretty sure this is the problem, I just don't know how to get around it. It's driving me crazy. Everything I can find on JSON/Android uses a JSON that begins with an array, which my code would take care of. I just can't figure out how to do the above: get the second object's array. Any help would be extremely appreciated. I've been racking my brain for days trying different things. The app runs sometimes and doesn't show anything on screen, other times the app just crashes with an error that says String cannot convert JSONObject, and a few times I got null pointer errors. Like I mentioned, I think it's because I'm trying to call the array on "Identified" when I should be calling it on "information". But I can't figure out how to get past Identified and then jump into the information array. I'm sure it's just a few lines of code in the right place, but I don't know where.

The JSON is as follows:

```
  {
  "identified": "yes",
  "Information":
  [
        {
            "state": "Arkansas",
            "type": "landlocked",
            "additionalinfo": "{ search: 'online', website: 'http://states.arkansas.com', latitudeandlongitude: '93905, 63550}",
            "outdoorfun": "yes",
            "cold": "no"
        },
        {
            "state": "chicago",
            "type": "windy",
            "additionalinfo": "{ search: 'online', website: 'http://states.chicago.com', latitudeandlongitude: '23905, 45355}",
            "outdoorfun": "no",
            "cold": "yes"
        }
   ]
}
```

And the main part of the Activity class code is below:

```
// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_IDENTIFIED = "id";
private static final String TAG_INFORMATION = "information";
private static final String TAG_STATE = "state";
private static final String TAG_TYPE = "type";
private static final String TAG_ADDITIONALINFO = "additionalinfo";
private static final String TAG_OUTDOORFUN = "outdoorfun";
private static final String TAG_COLD = "cold";


// contacts JSONArray
JSONArray information = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Hashmap for ListView
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> stateList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    // Creating JSON Parser instance
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    // getting JSON string from URL
    JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

        try{ 



        for(int i = 0; i < information.length(); i++){
            information =json.getJSONArray(TAG_INFORMATION);

            JSONObject c = information.getJSONObject(i);

            // Storing each json item in variable
            String name = c.getString(TAG_STATE);
            String type = c.getString(TAG_TYPE);

            // Phone number is agin JSON Object
            JSONObject additionalinfo = c.getJSONObject(ADDITIONALINFO);
            String outdoorfun = c.getString(TAG_OUTDOORFUN);
            String cold = c.getString(TAG_COLD);


            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
            map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
            map.put(TAG_TYPE, type);
            map.put(TAG_OUTDOORFUN, outdoorfun);




            informationList.add(map);
        }
        }
     catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    /**
     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
     * */
    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, informationList,
            R.layout.list_item,
            new String[] {TAG_NAME, TAG_TYPE, TAG_OUTDOORFUN }, new int[] {
                    R.id.name, R.id.type, R.id.outdoorfun });

    setListAdapter(adapter);

    // selecting single ListView item
    ListView lv = getListView();

    // Launching new screen on Selecting Single ListItem
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // getting values from selected ListItem
            String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name)).getText().toString();
            String type = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.type)).getText().toString();
            String outdoorfun = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.outdoorfun)).getText().toString();




            // Starting new intent
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleMenuItemActivity.class);
            in.putExtra(TAG_NAME, name);
            in.putExtra(TAG_TYPE, type);
            in.putExtra(TAG_OUTDOORFUN, outdoorfun);
            startActivity(in);

        }
    });
```

The Parser is here:

```
    herepackage com.androidhive.jsonparsing;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser extends Activity {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }


    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();           

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

And the Single List Activity is Here:

```
    package com.androidhive.jsonparsing;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SingleMenuItemActivity  extends Activity {

    // JSON node keys

    private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
    private static final String TAG_INFORMATION = "information";
    private static final String TAG_STATE = "state";
    private static final String TAG_TYPE = "type";
    private static final String TAG_ADDITIONALINFO = "additionalinfo";
    private static final String TAG_OUTDOORFUN = "outdoorfun";
    private static final String TAG_COLD = "cold";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.single_list_item);

        // getting intent data
        Intent in = getIntent();

        // Get JSON values from previous intent
        String name = in.getStringExtra(TAG_NAME);
        String type = in.getStringExtra(TAG_TYPE);
        String outdoorfun = in.getStringExtra(TAG_OUTDOORFUN);

        // Displaying all values on the screen
        TextView lblName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name_label);
        TextView lblType = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.type_label);
        TextView lblOutdoorfun = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.outdoorfun_label);

        lblName.setText(name);
        lblType.setText(type);
        lblOutdoorfun.setText(outdoorfun);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you might want to take a look at http://json.org/; your JSON is not valid, so that's probably causing your error regarding Strings to JSONObjects. Also, you might want to take a look at the Android JSON parsing classes' documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/package-summary.html

Comment: Another comment: you might want to cut down on what you're trying to do so you can focus on getting the JSON to parse and see output on LogCat, for example, before trying to get your activity and ListView working.

Comment: I just checked on JSONLint and the JSON is valid. This is the exact code that was running the android hive tutorial and it works fine. The only difference is that my JSON has an object before the array. If I can do something with that object before jumping into the array then everything should work fine. I just don't know what to do with that object. I've tried getting it out of the JSON thru code right above the for loop of the array and putting it into a string. but to no avail. The for loop will work fine as soon as i figure out what to do about the identified object in the way of my array.

Comment: The activity and listview already work from when i ran the tutorial so there's nothing wrong with that section of code. I think its just that first object that I'm neglecting that's throwing everything off. I don't know what to do with it.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. The JSON is indeed valid, but the value of "additionalinfo" is not a JSON object, but a string. Is that intentional?

Comment: Post you LogCat error log.

Comment: No that was supposed to say String. Not causing my prob tho. just changed it.

Comment: Would you mind updating the code to what you're currently working with?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want `TAG_INFORMATION = "Information"` or your JSON to read

```
"information":
  [
```

Your cases don't match.

I also think you might need to retrieve the information array outside the for loop (that is, `json.getJSONArray` should probably be outside the for loop.

Comment: I had already pulled json.getJSONArray out of the for loop. I thought of that one. And fixed the typo. What I'm not getting is that this exact same code I have here would work for a JSON that didn't have that "Identified" object there. Removing that ID object would make the JSON exactly the same as the tutorial. So what's different. I think all i need to do is at least acknowledge that object somehow right above the for loop. and then the code will go on to the next object...right?

Comment: LOGCAT says I have a NULL Pointer at information =json.getJSONArray(TAG_INFORMATION);

Comment: Are you getting a printout from `Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());`? Because I'm guessing that maybe that function call is returning null.

Comment: And now I'm getting Value of type String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: You shouldn't need to acknowledge any of the other keys that you don't need. The Android JSON parser isn't that kind of linear parser; you can just ask for the things you want by name.

Comment: Yea the above is my printout from that

Comment: So the "Value of type String cannot be converted to JSONObject" is definitely coming from the Parser? And definitely from the `catch (JSONException e)`?

Comment: Yes it is. That's the only place i have that exception

Comment: http get anyone. o.O  what a stupid mistake...there were a few other things but everything is working fine now. thanks for all your help man.